# Rabbit MQ What data to send as a Message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, esb

i am going to integrate some applications using RabbitMQ. Now i am facing the design issue. Right now i am having one application producing message and one application consuming it (in future more are possible). Both applications have access to some database. Application A is some kind of registration application when it receives registration request it sends message to on rabitmq. Now application b receives this message and its task is to load the registration data to elasticsearch server. Now i have some options

1. consumer will read the message and id from q and load the data and send it to the elastic search server
   fastest throughput. Because things will move in asynchronous way. other process which may be running on separate
   server will loading the data and sending to elastic server
2. consumer will read the message and id from the q and then call the rest service to load the company data.
   will take more time for processing each request as it will be having network overhead.although it will save time to data load 
   but will add network delay. And it will by pass the ESB(Message Broker) also. (i personally think if i am using esb in my application
   it is not necessary that i use it for every single method call)
3. send all the registration data in the message. consumer will receive it and just upload it to elasticsearch server.

which approach i should follow?

Comment: can you please clarify the exact difference between 1 and 3?

Comment: in one application A is just sending the Id of the required data in the message and application B loads data from database on the basis of this id and uploads it to elastic, and in 3 application A is sending complete object in the message and application B receives the object and uploads it to elasticsearch server

Comment: If you can, option 3.  Application B purpose seems to index, not to query. Application A seems to already have load the data needs by Application B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there are many components to your application set up that is hard to take into account and suggest a straightforward answer. I would suggest that you should look into each design and identify I/O points, calls over the network and data volume exchanged over the network. Then depending on the load you expect and the volume of data you expect to store **over time** I would suggest you hierarchize these bottlenecks giving a higher score depending on the severity of it. Identify the one solution that has the lowest score and go with that.

I would suggest you should benchmark the difference between sending only the iq or sending the whole object. I would expect that the difference is negligible.

One suggestion. Make your objects immutable. It is not directly relevant with what you are describing but in situations like yours, where components are operating "blindly" you will find that knowing that an object has not changed state is a big assurance.

Comment: db I/O is also there in case 3 because this message will be sent at the end of multi step process. so the application A will have to query the data of previous steps from db and then will be able to send it as a message.

Comment: application A if it sends only the Id will it not perform the database query before sending the id?

Comment: it will perform db operation of saving the data but as far as id is concerned it will get from session

Comment: I assume that you use an ORM  so you get the Id from the session, you create the object and then you save it. If this is the case then you have created the object once and you have saved it to the db. no need to query the db to get the same object on the other side. So my answer would be the same. In any case I will edit it to try to clarify my point

Comment: @idipious it is a seven step process at every step i am saving some data at last step i am not saving complete data it is only a subset. so i will have to query the data of previous steps and i cant use ORM due to client choice.

Comment: and i am new to message broker. what is routine practice? we send only events with minimal data? or we send complete data over it?

Comment: It is always best to send as little data as possible but this does not mean that it makes a big difference in your case. As I said in my answer I would benchmark it.